# UnsatisfiedDependencyException and Circular Dependency

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I am trying to make some Spring Boot legacy code build and run, but it fails with:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataLoader' defined in file [......\bootstrap\DataLoader.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'organizationServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setAssessmentService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'assessmentServiceImpl': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    
......
    
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'organizationServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setAssessmentService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'assessmentServiceImpl': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:676)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1411)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592)
    at ........
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'assessmentServiceImpl': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:139)
```

DataLoader class is:

```
@Component
public class DataLoader implements ApplicationRunner {

    private final OrganizationService organizationService;

    private List<String> organizationNames = Arrays.asList(
        ...some long list of string literals...

    );

    public DataLoader(OrganizationService organizationService) {
        this.organizationService = organizationService;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) {
        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(organizationService.findAll())) {
            addOrganizations();
        }
    }

    private void addOrganizations() {
        organizationNames.forEach(name -> {
            OrganizationRequest organization = new OrganizationRequest();
            organization.setName(name);
            if (
            ....irrelevant code....
            }
            organizationService.save(organization);
        });
    }

}
```

and OrganizationServiceImpl class is:

```
@Service
public class OrganizationServiceImpl implements OrganizationService {

    private final OrganizationRepository organizationRepository;
    private final AddressService addressService;
    private final ContactService contactService;
    private final SupplierQualifierService supplierQualifierService;
    private final MonitoringScopeService monitoringScopeService;
    private final FinancialService financialsService;

    private DocumentService documentService;
    private AssessmentService assessmentService;

    @Getter
    private Map<Long, Set<QuestionType>> questionTypesForAssessmentByOrganization = new HashMap<>();

    public OrganizationServiceImpl(OrganizationRepository organizationRepository, AddressService addressService, ContactService contactService, SupplierQualifierService supplierQualifierService, MonitoringScopeService monitoringScopeService, FinancialService financialsService ) {
        this.organizationRepository = organizationRepository;
        this.addressService = addressService;
        this.contactService = contactService;
        this.supplierQualifierService = supplierQualifierService;
        this.monitoringScopeService = monitoringScopeService;
        this.financialsService = financialsService;
    }

    //workaround for circular dependency
    @Autowired
    public void setAssessmentService(AssessmentService assessmentService) {
        this.assessmentService = assessmentService;
    }

    // to prevent circular dependency problem ...
    @Autowired 
    public void setDocumentService(DocumentService documentService) {
        this.documentService = documentService;
    }

    @Override
    public Organization findById(Long id) {
        Optional<Organization> organization = organizationRepository.findById(id);
        return organization.orElse(new Organization());
    }

    @Override
    public List<Organization> findAll() {
        return organizationRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Organization save(OrganizationRequest request) {
    ....long not relevant code...

        return savedOrganization;
    }


    ....long not relevant code, some business logic...

}
```

AssessmentServiceImpl class is:

```
@Service
public class AssessmentServiceImpl implements AssessmentService {

private final AssessmentRepository assessmentRepository;
private final OrganizationService organizationService;
private final AnswerService answerService;
private final QuestionService questionService;

private Map<QuestionType, Integer> numberOfQuestionsByType = new HashMap<>();

public AssessmentServiceImpl(AssessmentRepository assessmentRepository, OrganizationService organizationService, AnswerService answerService, QuestionService questionService) {
    this.assessmentRepository = assessmentRepository;
    this.organizationService = organizationService;
    this.answerService = answerService;
    this.questionService = questionService;
}

@PostConstruct
public void postConstruct() {
    for (QuestionType type : QuestionType.values()) {
        numberOfQuestionsByType.put(type, questionService.findByQuestionType(type).size());
    }
}


... some business logic code....
```

}

Chain of failed dependency injection is:

```
Error creating bean with name 'dataLoader':
Error creating bean with name 'organizationServiceImpl': 
Error creating bean with name 'assessmentServiceImpl':
```

But I don't see direct cause for it.

I see that original developer ran into cyclic dependency issues, but from what I Googled it seems this should be appropriate solution:

```
//workaround for circular dependency
@Autowired
public void setAssessmentService(AssessmentService assessmentService) {
   this.assessmentService = assessmentService;
}

// to prevent circular dependency problem ...
@Autowired 
public void setDocumentService(DocumentService documentService) {
    this.documentService = documentService;
}
```

Comment: Is there any XML file autowiring beans apart from the `@Autowired` we can see?

Comment: What I see from the exception is that you are trying to load some data during a bean creation which is failing because of some wrong sql statement or whatever.

Comment: @ NeoChiri no XML files, just @Autowiring

Answer (score 1):

The error-message states that when creating the bean it has troubles with your datasource:

**InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet**

I suspect a problem when reading the database. There is no circular dependency issue. It is a perfect bean-creation chain. Spring detects a circular dependency and shows a diffrent error message.

Try to uncomment the code in the @PostConstruct and run the application again.

```
@PostConstruct
public void postConstruct() {
    for (QuestionType type : QuestionType.values()) {
        numberOfQuestionsByType.put(type, 
           questionService.findByQuestionType(type).size());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The stacktrace is pretty straight forward , your bean creation of `AssessmentService` in AssessmentServiceImpl is failing because of sql `SQLGrammarException`:

```
nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

which means that hibernate is having issues executing the query that you provided in your bean post construct.
Most probably this code : `questionService.findByQuestionType(type).size()` is causing the issue for you during bean creation. Analyse the logs more to confirm or share the full logs.

Check the `Entity` class to ensure everything is mapped correctly and all the annotations are provided correctly. Try enabling the  hibernate logs for more detailed log for analysis.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you are trying to fetch some response from the DB, into a resultset. The query does not return the entire object, instead only a part of the object or combination of two or more classes. Your hibernate class does not have the matching constructor, thus it is unable to initialize your object.

Answer (score 0):

Thank for all the comments, it brought me back to the right track.
Problem was in hibernate settings:

```
hibernate:
  ddl-auto: none
```

so I changed it to:

```
hibernate:
  ddl-auto: create
```

and it works now.